# XGBoost4J successfully built but can't import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.{DMatrix => JDMatrix}

Tags: scala, xgboost

I carefully followed the installation instructions from [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/index.html), paid attention to set  JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/

The installation through `mvn package` returns BUILD SUCCESS. However, when I tried to run BasicWalkThrough.scala from the example folder I got an error on

```
<console>:14: error: not found: value ml
   import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.{DMatrix => JDMatrix}
```

Can anybody help to fix this please?

OS:OSX 10.12

Answer (score 0):

You need to run spark-shell with conf option pointing to your built xboost jar:

```
./bin/spark-shell --conf spark.jars=/xgboost/jvm-packages/xgboost4j-example/target/xgboost4j-example-0.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```